# How to get data from last x months Postgres Sql Query where date field is a timestamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a sql query where I can get data from the last 3 months. Specifically, I want to see how much each customer spent over the last 3 months. My date field is a timestamp with timezone (e.g., 2017-07-14 00:56:43.833191+00").

I'm not trying to get the last 90 days of data, but actually the last 3 months, so if it's currently July 14, 2017, I'd want to get data between April 1, 2017 and June 30, 2017.

Here's what I currently have and it works great if the 3 months are in the same year, but it doesn't work across years, meaning that if the current date is February 15, 2017, I'd want it to return data from November 1, 2016 through January 31, 2017.  But, that doesn't work.

Here's my current query.  I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks!

```
select sum(amount), customer_id
from payments
where (date_part('month',payment_date) < (date_part('month',current_timestamp)-1) and
       date_part('month',payment_date) >=  (date_part('month',current_timestamp)-3) ) and 
       (date_part('year',date_created) = date_part('year',current_timestamp))
group by customer_id
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I think `date_trunc()` is much simpler:

```
select sum(amount), customer_id
from payments
where payment_date >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '3 month' and
      payment_date < date_trunc('month', now())
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: awesome - worked like a charm.  I also tested it by changing now() to date '2017-02-15' to see if it would properly go back into November 2016 and it did.  Thank you!!

Comment: btw, not sure if this is allowed or if I need to create a separate question, but a follow up - how can I only show results where the sum(amount) > 5 ?  if I try that i get an error that I can't have an aggregate function in a where clause.  Thanks! :)

Comment: @Jacob . . . Strictly speaking it should be another question, but the answer is `having sum(amount) > 5`.